# Jackson - parse different model under same key at runtime

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a specific json response from server, where under a key the content would be of different models also at a time only one of the model data would be present under the key.

While parsing the response into POJO how can I specify object type at runtime based on other field of contentType on same model.

Following is the code for better understanding of scenario.

Here content_type is type A and so under `"content"` key there would be model for object of class TypeA

```
"scheduled_content": {

  "some_field": "value",
  "content_type": "typeA",
  "content" : {
          "some_field" : "value"
          "more_feilds" : "value"
   }
 }
```

Here content_type is type B and so under `"content"` key there would be model for object of class TypeB

```
"scheduled_content": {

  "some_field": "value",
  "content_type": "typeB",
  "content" : {
          "some_field_b" : "value"
          "more_fields_for_b" : "value"
   }
 }
```

How can I write POJO classes to parse such json response?
The type classes are completely different models they don't have any field in common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is called, in Jackson JSON terms, polymorphic deserialization by property name.

Here is how I do it with Jackson 2.1.4:

First create an abstract class `ScheduledContent` with common members and an abstract method that would operate on the content. Use the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation to mark the JSON property that would resolve the specific implementation and the `JsonSubTypes` annotation to register the subtypes by the values of the property previously specified:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "content_type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "typeA", value = ScheduledAContent.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "typeB", value = ScheduledBContent.class)
})
public abstract class ScheduledContent {
  private String someField;

  @JsonSetter("some_field")
  public void setSomeField(String someField) {
    this.someField = someField;
  }

  public abstract void doSomethingWithContent();
}
```

The subtypes registration can also be done on the `ObjectMapper` as you will see later.

Then add the specific implementation for the `ScheduledAContent` class:

```
public class ScheduledAContent extends ScheduledContent {
    private TypeAContent content;

    public void setContent(TypeAContent content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingWithContent() {
        System.out.println("someField: " + content.getSomeField());
        System.out.println("anotherField: " + content.getAnotherField());
    }
}
```

with `TypeAContent` being:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

public class TypeAContent {
    private String someField;
    private String anotherField;

    @JsonSetter("some_field")
    public void setSomeField(String someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    @JsonSetter("another_field")
    public void setAnotherField(String anotherField) {
        this.anotherField = anotherField;
    }

    public String getAnotherField() {
        return anotherField;
    }
}
```

and also for the `ScheduledBContent` class:

```
public class ScheduledBContent extends ScheduledContent {
    private TypeBContent content;

    public void setContent(TypeBContent content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingWithContent() {
        System.out.println("someField: " + content.getSomeField());
        System.out.println("anotherField: " + content.getAnotherField());
    }
}
```

with `TypeBContent` being:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

public class TypeBContent {
    private String someField;
    private String anotherField;

    @JsonSetter("some_field_b")
    public void setSomeField(String someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    @JsonSetter("another_field_b")
    public void setAnotherField(String anotherField) {
        this.anotherField = anotherField;
    }

    public String getAnotherField() {
        return anotherField;
    }
}
```

And a simple Test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.NamedType;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonA = "{" +
                "\"some_field\": \"main_some_field1\"," +
                "\"content_type\": \"typeA\"," +
                "\"content\" : {" +
                "    \"some_field\" : \"content_some_field\"," +
                "    \"another_field\" : \"content_another_field\"" +
                "}}";

        String jsonB = "{" +
                "\"some_field\": \"main_some_field2\"," +
                "\"content_type\": \"typeB\"," +
                "\"content\" : {" +
                "    \"some_field_b\" : \"content_some_field_b\"," +
                "    \"another_field_b\" : \"content_another_field_b\"" +
                "}}";


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        /*
         * This is another way to register the subTypes if you want to do it dynamically without the use of the
         * JsonSubTypes annotation in the ScheduledContent class
         */
//        mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(ScheduledAContent.class, "typeA"));
//        mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(ScheduledBContent.class, "typeB"));

        try {
            ScheduledContent scheduledAContent = mapper.readValue(jsonA, ScheduledContent.class);
            scheduledAContent.doSomethingWithContent();

            ScheduledContent scheduledBContent = mapper.readValue(jsonB, ScheduledContent.class);
            scheduledBContent.doSomethingWithContent();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

that will produce the output:

```
someField: content_some_field
anotherField: content_another_field
someField: content_some_field_b
anotherField: content_another_field_b
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @JsonSetter in the setter methods may help. But in this case you will need to create setter methods for each type of fields in "content".

```
@JsonSetter("some_field")
public void setSomeField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

@JsonSetter("some_field_b")
public void setSomeField2(String field2) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
```