# How to use @JsonProperty annotation with array containing elements of different format

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using an API that uses in requests & responses json array in a SpringBoot App with elements of various format and I'm struggling to dynamically get the right class to be used for serialisation/deserialisation of elements of such array.

Here is a simplified description of the json:

```
{
    "parameters" :[
        {
            "name": "elementA",
            "value": "valueOfElementAsAString"
        },
        {
            "name": "elementB",
            "value": "valueOfElementBAsString"
        },
        {
            "name": "elementC",
            "value": [
                {
                    "label":"label1",
                    "size":"size1"
                },
                {
                    "label":"label2",
                    "size":"size2"
                }

            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

Considering the following base classes:

```
class SimpleElement {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public String value;

    //constructor & stuff 
}


class ComplexElement {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public ArrayList<ComplexElementValue> value = new ArrayList<ComplexElementValue>();

    //constructor & stuff 
}

class ComplexElementValue {
    @JsonProperty("label")
    public String label;
    @JsonProperty("size")
    public String size;  

    //constructor & stuff   
}
```

Serialization/Deserialisation of individual Simple or Complex Elements works fine but how shall I declare my class Parameters using @JsonProperty to get the full array correctly handled ?:

```
class Parameters {
    ???
}
```

Based on what I read, I've got the impression I have to write custom deserialiser & serialiser but before doing so I would like to make sure there is no simpler way ?

At the moment, considering I've got n x simpleElements and 1 x complexElement, I get it to work with such a class:

```
class Parameter {
   @JsonProperty("parameters")
   public MultiElement element;

   public class MultiElement {
      public ArrayList<SimpleElement> regularElements;
      public ComplexElement complexElement;
   }
  
   //constructor & stuff 
}
```

and handling the deserialisation/serialisation of the json "manually" using a JsonNode library (in this case org.camunda.spin.json.SpinJsonNode), but this sounds for me like a temporary solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For handling dynamic json using jackson.

1. JsonNode is simple one.

   public class Paramter {
   private List parameters;
   //Getters and setters
   public static class Parameters {

   ```
          private String name;
          private JsonNode value;
         //Getters and setters
        }
   ```

   }
2. this will help you correctly if if need concrete class
   [Jackson - parse different model under same key at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923752/jackson-parse-different-model-under-same-key-at-runtime)

Comment: thx a lot for your answer, ref to your point 2, I actually had seen that but as I have up to 40 different values for the "name" of my simpleElement, I've got the impression that I have to declare 40 times:  @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "<possible_name_values>", value = SimpleElementDerivedFromCommonAbstractClass.class) and then one line with @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "elementC", value = ComplexElementDerivedFromCommonAbstractClass.class)   ? or is there a way to only declare 2 lines, one for the ComplexElement and another to say for all other values of name pick the SimpleElement class ?

Comment: I am also watching for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically try to convert json to java class using any online converters like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Try using modelmapper library for object mapping. Like mapping json objects to java objects.

Comment: If json message have _class attribute I guess spring will be able to map it. I have used this with mongodb. If that doesnt work or not feasible check this

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsoncomponent